# Output behaviour in different compilers

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

class Y
{
      public:
             Y();
};

class X
{
      public:
             void foo() {}
             friend Y::Y();

             X()
             {
                    Y::Y();  //Statement 1
             }
};

Y::Y()
{
   std::cout << "Hello";
}

int main()
{
    X a;
    Y::Y();      //Statenent 2
}
```

The above program produces the output `HelloHello` on Dev c++ and codepad. But when i run on Code::Blocks it gives error `remove the reduntant Y::`

If i replace statement 1 and 2 withh `Y();` , the program produces the output in all 3. Why so?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same warning flags on every compiler?

Comment: @trojanfoe  I am using all the IDE's default. I dont know anything about warning flags.

Comment: That's where you should start looking.

Comment: Dev C++, codepad and Code::Blocks are not compilers, they are IDE's. What compiler(s) are you using?

Comment: Is `Y::Y();` undefined in C++ standard? Why the hell would it work on 1 compiler and produce error on others?(irrespective of the warning flags)

Comment: GCC is used in Dev C++ and Code::Blocks

Comment: @Shreyas: What version of the gcc compiler are you using? BTW, saying Code::Blocks or DevC++ does not mean much, the exact compiler and version that is used by the environment is what matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside every class `X`, `X` can be used to refer to that class. This allows, for example,

```
struct X {
  struct Y {
    static int f();
  };
};
int X::Y::f() {
  Y y;
  return 0;
}
int main() {
  return X::Y::f();
}
```

to work, even though `Y` *appears* to not be in scope inside the definition of `X::Y::f`.

The way the standard specifies this has changed. In the original C++ standard, `Y` was simply treated as a member of `::X::Y`, and meant `::X::Y`. This interpretation made it impossible to refer to a constructor, since `X::X` was always a type. As a result, in the first TC, the standard was changed to make `X::X` refer to a type's constructor (in most cases).

One of your compilers implements the original C++ rules, the other the newer rules.

By the original rules, `Y::Y();` is just peachy. You're constructing a type. That type has an accessible constructor, so there is no issue.

By the newer rules, `Y::Y();` is an error. You're calling a constructor, and you're not allowed to explicitly call a constructor.

For those interested, this is core language issue 147.

Comment: I am not sure that the current rules state what you way. In particular 3.4.3.1/2 starts with *In a lookup in which the constructor is an acceptable lookup result* and goes on saying under which circumstances the constructor will be found. But the premise does not hold here, so in `Y::Y()`, `Y::Y` does not name the constructor. It specifically names that case: *For example, the constructor is not an acceptable lookup result in an elaborated-type-specifier so the constructor would not be used in place of the injected-class-name.* By the current standard, `Y::Y` is equivalent to `Y` or `Y::Y::Y`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas The text after the resolution of issue 147 did not include that. The text has been changed again later, and off hand, I am not sure in exactly which circumstances a constructor is *now* an acceptable lookup result, but that isn't the cause of the difference in compiler behaviour.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Core language issue 1310, if the proposed resolution is accepted, would make it unambiguous that `Y::Y();` is an error, and the suggested new wording is supposed to match the intent of the current wording.

Comment: A constructor is a valid result of lookup, for example, when declaring a `friend` or forwarding constructors, or more commonly in an out of class definition of the constructor itself. I imagine there are other cases, but those are the ones that pop to mind. At any rate with the current standard (and the CD for 2014) the code is valid and should be accepted. From the 2003 standard up to the 2011 standard `Y::Y()` would name the constructor and your answer would apply

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas As issue 1310 states, the standard does not actually define when a constructor is an acceptable lookup result. You suggest that in a context in which a constructor would always be an error, a constructor is not an acceptable lookup result, but the intent (according to that issue) is that a constructor is found whenever a function would be, even if that then results in an error. In other words, *for purposes of lookup*, a constructor is acceptable.

Comment: I was not there, so I don't know the intent of the current wording, but in the code above a constructor will never yield correct code, so I can imagine a definition of *acceptable lookup result for a constructor* that excluded that considering that it would *never* generate a valid program

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I was not there either, but that issue is by Jason Merrill, who does know the intent, and writes "The intent of the wording was that S::S would refer to the constructor except in lookups that ignore the names of functions," (You know you can read it online, right? [Here is a link.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1310))

Answer (score 0):

`Y::Y();` is wrong in C++. It shouldn't be allowed even by Dev C++.

If you mean to call the constructor for class `Y` you just have to create an object of type `Y`, e.g.

```
Y my; //creates an object named my of type Y
Y my = Y(); //same as above
Y(); // creates a temporary object which is destroyed in the following line
```

Comment: `Y my()` is a function declaration.

Comment: What do you mean by **wrong**? I worked for me on `GCC 4.4.5`

Comment: @HAL Compilers have bugs, too.

Comment: @jrok Sure, can you point us to something for more information or a bug report etc.

Comment: `Y::Y();` is not wrong in C++98, where it means exactly the same thing as `Y();` Older versions of compilers faithfully implement the C++98 rules where `Y::Y` is a valid way to refer to the type `Y`.

Answer (score 0):

```
If i replace statement 1 and 2 withh Y(); , the program produces the output in all 3. Why so?
```

The output is produced by calling the function `Y::Y()`. You do this either in the constructor of an instance of the class X or by calling the function directly.

But let's look at the variant "Statement 1". The code

```
int main ()
{
    X a;
}
```

creates an unused variable. The compiler might optimize it away. In that case the constructor is not called. That's dependend on the compiler and the actual options used. When you call the function Y::Y() directly it can't be optimized away and you get always the output.

Comment: @crashmstr What point did I miss? I described the `Why?` didn't I?

Comment: I think the compiler won't optimize `a` away because of the sides effects (prints). (And IMHO your answer is perfectly relevant to the question)

Comment: @harper He gets two "Hello"s, so it is not optimized, so your original version of your answer had nothing to do with the problem as asked. Also, the question really concerns *why* there is a difference between the three compilers tested (i.e. an error with one, or all work when code changed).